# Increment version text stored in a bash script file

Tags: bash, regex, sed, version

I have a bash file and I want to store a version text in it (preferably "`echo version 1.0.1`" so that it automatically prints out its own version when executed)

I am trying to make a command group that will update the version.

So far I've got

```
grep "echo version" ~/.bashrc | cut -c 14- | sed -e 's/\./\n/g'
```

which extracts "echo version 1.0.1", cuts out the "echo version " and splits the version between the dots

```
1
0
1
```

and I'm hitting my limit of regex, bash, and google-foo to extract the last number (patch version) which I could increment and write back to file.

Mainly, how do I get that last number?

Also if there's anything much better I should be doing, please do suggest.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F'[ .]' '/^echo version/ {print $1,$2,$3"."$4"."$5+1}' ~/.bashrc
```

Output:

```
echo version 1.0.2
```

`-F'[ .]'`: field separator(s) blank and dot

`/^echo version/`: search for line starting (`^`) with `echo version`

`print $1,$2`: print strings separated by a blank

`$5+1`: increment string/value by 1

Answer (score 4):

perl to the rescue

```
$ cat file
echo version 1.0.1
$ perl -i -pe 's/echo version \d+\.\d+\.\K(\d+)/ $1+1 /e' file
$ cat file
echo version 1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use `bash-semver`:

> https://github.com/fmahnke/shell-semver

```sh
## Use bash-semver
## https://github.com/fmahnke/shell-semver
#===========

#Increment semantic versioning strings in shell scripts.
./increment_version.sh
usage: increment_version.sh [-Mmp] major.minor.patch

./increment_version.sh -p 0.0.0
#0.0.1

./increment_version.sh -m 0.0.3
#0.1.0

./increment_version.sh -M 1.1.15
#2.0.0

./increment_version.sh -Mmp 2.3.4
#3.1.1
```